Are the geodesics given by the semicircles in the Poincaré upper-half plane parameterized by arc length?
Given a parameterized surface such that $E = \frac{1}{v^2}$, $F = 0$, $G = \frac{1}{v^2}$ I am asked to prove for curves of the form $(u(s),v(s)) = (a + r\tanh(s),r\operatorname{sech}(s))$ that:
(1) They correspond to the semicircles with center at $v = 0$.
(2) They are geodesic.
(3) Its image by $\varphi$ is parameterized by arc length.
Where $E,F,G$ denote the coefficients of the first fundamental form and $\varphi$ the parametrization of the surface.
I've already prove (1) and (2) but I'm stucked on (3). I know that the problem surface is an abstract surface, known as Poincare upper-half plane and therefore there is no such $\varphi$ so I find the question a bit confusing. I also know that this model has a non-standart arc length element ds given by $ds^2 = \frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$ but since it is not mentioned in the problem I understand that I should not use it.
It probably won't be a difficult question but it's the first time I've done something related to abstract surfaces, any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

I'll answer with just a hint: The arc length is mentioned in the problem.
You just have to compare the two coordinate systems correctly, by letting $x=u$ and $y=v$.
When you make that comparison, you will see that the formulas $$E=\frac{1}{v^2}=\frac{1}{y^2} \qquad F=0 \qquad G=\frac{1}{v^2}=\frac{1}{y^2} = \frac{1}{y^2}
$$
correspond exactly to the formula
$$ds^2 \,\, = \,\, \frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2} \,\, = \,\, \underbrace{\frac{1}{y^2}}_E  \, dx^2 \, + \, \underbrace{0\vphantom{\frac{1}{y^2}}}_F \, dx \, dy \, + \, \underbrace{\frac{1}{y^2}}_G \, dy^2
$$
